# custom Ubuntu image into Azure

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, azure, cloud-storage, linux-on-azure

I want to upload my custom Ubuntu image(configured with some packages) into Azure. I have a .vmdk which I have converted to .vhd. Can I upload it directly to Azure and use it to spin up new instances? Any links or method will be highly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I upload it directly to Azure and use it to spin up new instances? Any links or method will be highly welcome.

Of course you can. But you need to generalize the VM to remove the unique ID.

For detail information, please follow this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/).

If you want to create a VM with this VHD instead of uploading it as a template, then, please follow the guide below:

[Create a VM from a specialized VHD disk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-from-specialized-vhd)